# C++ Circular Dependency Explanation

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, circular-dependency

I have a basic example of a circular dependency using smart pointers.
I've been looking for some explanations, and I know how to solve this problem, but I want to know what it is happening behind the scenes.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Child;
class Parent {
  public:
    shared_ptr<Child> child;
    string name;
    Parent(string n) : name(n) {
      cout << "Parent: " << name << " constructor" << endl;
    }
    ~Parent() {
      cout << "Parent: " << name << " destructor" << endl;
    }
};

class Child {
  public:
    shared_ptr<Parent> parent;
    string name;
    Child(string n) : name(n) {
      cout << "Child: " << name << " constructor" << endl;
    }
    ~Child() {
      cout << "Child: " << name << " destructor" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  shared_ptr<Parent> parent = make_shared<Parent>("Dad");//parent.use_count() => 1
  shared_ptr<Child> child = make_shared<Child>("Child");//child.use_count() => 1
  parent->child = child;//child.use_count() => 2
  child->parent = parent;//parent.use_count() => 2
  return 0;
}
//what happend at the end of the program?
//what happend when the shared_ptr destructors were called?
//was parent.use_count() decremented or is still 2?
//was child.use_count() decremented or is still 2?
```

Output:

```
Parent: Dad constructor
Child: Child constructor
```

What I want to know is the following

- what happen when the shared_ptr destructors are called?
- is parent.use_count() decremented or is still 2?
- is child.use_count() decremented or is still 2?

I suppose the shared_ptr destructor code is something like:

```
~shared_ptr() {
  //I want to know what it is happening right here
  if (canDeletePointer(pointer)) {
    delete pointer;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI, this is not a Parent-Child relationship.  Usually Parent and Child involves inheritance.  You have two classes that have pointers to each other.

Comment: In this example I did not want use inheritance, I could use other names, but I wanted to use Parent and Child instead of A, and B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When shared_ptr destructor is called, it decrements the link count, and if it becomes zero, it executes the destructor of the object and frees the memory.
- After the `main()` function ends two shared pointers get removed, so their destructors are executed, decreasing the count from 2 to 1 for both son and dad.

Comment: Obvious though it might seem, I would state explicitly that this leads to leaking both objects.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step

1. `Parent` created and made shared in local variable `parent`. For ease of reading we'll call this allocation Parent. Parent count 1
2. `Child` created and made shared in local variable `child`. For ease of reading we'll call this allocation Child. Child count 1
3. `parent` updated to point at `child`. Child count 2
4. `child` updated to point at `parent`. Parent count 2
5. main ends
6. `child` destroyed. Child count 1
7. `parent` destroyed Parent count 1

Child and Parent are not destroyed because their respective counts never reach zero. The program exits and the OS reclaims all of the memory without their destructors being run. If this was a portion of a larger program, Child and Parent would go on taking up space in memory until program exit, unless some extreme lengths were taken to locate them, because their only external link was destroyed.